# Number of ways n-1 edges may be chosen to form a connected graph with n nodes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, nodes, graph-theory, edges

Basically, you require n-1 edges, to make a connected graph with n nodes. I would like to know if there is any theory behind finding the number of distinct ways you can select the n-1 edges, from the total n(n-1)/2 edges that are possible, such that the graph remains connected.

Comment: This might be better here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are exactly `nn-2` connected graphs with vertex set `{1,...n}` for `n > 0`.  This result is known as [Cayley's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula).

Comment: Ive spent close to 3 hours thinking about this, finally i can read the proof and be satisfied!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  The fun thing about combinatorics is that it's so easy to ask a question that's really, really hard to answer.  In fact, the question "How many connected graphs are there on `n` vertices with `n+k` edges?" is almost totally open for `k > -1`!  (See [this paper](http://mathcs.emory.edu/~tomasz/papers/sparse.ps).)